# Ordered pairs, property, proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

[image]
Can some please make an exposition of this proof. I certainly am able to understand the trivial direction. But on the interesting direction, the first case is that (b) and (c) must hold and the second is (a) and (d) must hold and produce the desired conclusion. It is clear to me that if the first case holds then the conclusion is reached. On the otherhand, if the second hold, i cannot quite grasp why we can get either $u=y$ or $v=y$ part. Can anyone help me. Can someone also draw the sketch of this proof, why was it done this way. Thanks.

This is from the elements of set theory by enderton.

Comment: The non-trivial direction exploit several properties of set. First one: $A=B$ iff $A \subseteq B$ and $B \subseteq A$. Thus, we consider $\{ \{ u \}, \{ u,v \} \} \subseteq \{ \{ x \}, \{ x,y \} \}$. Again, we have $A \subseteq B$ iff $(x \in A \to x \in B)$, for every $x$. Thus, we must have that the elements of the set on the left, i.e. $\{ u \}$ and $\{ u,v \}$ must belong to the set on the right.

Comment: Now: if $\{ u \} \in \{ \{ x \}, \{ x,y \} \}$, due to the fact that the set on the right has only two elements: $\{ x \}$ and $\{ x,y \}$, either $\{ u \} = \{ x \}$ or $\{ u \} = \{ x,y \}$. For the same reason, from $\{ u,v \} \in \{ \{ x \}, \{ x,y \} \}$ we have that  either $\{ u,v \} = \{ x \}$ or $\{ u,v \} = \{ x,y \}$.

Comment: IN conclusion, there are four possible cases: 1) (a) and (c), 2) (a) and (d), 3) (b) and (c) and 4) (b) and (d). 3) and 4) are similar: Ok. When he consider (c), he is considering case 1) (a) and (c). The last one is 2) (a) and (d). Now, if $\{ u \} = \{ x \}$, for the same arguiment above we have $u=x$. Now consider $\{ u,v \} = \{ x,y \}$; again, it means that: for every element $z$, if $z \in \{ u,v \}$ then $z \in \{ x,y \}$; consider $u$ as $z$ and we have that $u \in \{ x,y \}$. Thus, either $u=x$ or $u=y$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, please can you explain the case 1)(a) and (c). I understand in this case that $u = v = x$ because of (c) and $u = x$ because of (a).  These tell us that $u = v = x$. But we haven't shown that $v = y$ as required.

Answer (score 0):

Assume (x,y) = (u,v).  Thus
{x} = $\cap$(x,y) = $\cap$(u,v) = {u}.  x = u.
So {x,y} = $\cup${{x}, {x,y}} = $\cup${{x}, {x,v}} = {x,v}.
This reduces the tedium of separate cases to two.
Namely, x = y and not x = y.